# How to access boolean variable in a protected method in an abtract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermockito

just wanted to know how I can WhiteboxImpl.getInternalState(classname, "x"); I want to get the value of x, which is a boolean. x is in a protected method under an abstract class (which I mocked already) But whenever I run my junit test it say field is not found in the heirarchy of the class. Is there a way to access x? Thanks in advance

```
  public abstract class abstractClass {
  
  String sampletext;
  int sampleint;

  public abstractClass (String sampletext, int sampleint) {
  this.sampletext = sampletext;
  this.sameplint = sampleint;
  }

  protected void protectedMethod(ServerSocketChannel samplechannel) {
  try{
  boolean x = false;
  
  if (SocketChannel != null) {
  Socket samplesocket = SocketChannel.socket();
  
  if(samplesocket.isConnected()) {
  x = true;
  }


}
```

`
edited.
basically the code somewhat looks like this. I'm trying to
WhiteboxImpl.getInternalState(absClass, "x");
and it just returns field is not found in class hierarchy. Maybe it's impossible to get to the field..? My end goal is to assertTrue x so that it proves the test case entered the if condition for the junit test. Since it's a void method I don't know what to assert besides that.

ps. absClass is the mocked instance of the abstract class.

Comment: `x` is **in** a protected method? I.e. it's a local variable? Odds are you simply can't get to it.

Comment: could you post the code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed, it's a software of our company and there are confidentiality issues. Basically the issue is as I described it. but I'll just edit my post with dummy code.